# GitHub pages custom website not updating after commit

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a website that is hosted in github pages. It's all custom, I've never used Jeckill etc. 
Anyway, it worked fine till today. Usually when I push updates I can see the changes instantly. Right now I pushed some changes but I can't see any update. I needed to added a script but even the tag  doesn't show up on the actual website, but I can see it in the repository.

What I've tried:

- CTRL-SHIFT-R the page
- Incognito Navigation
- Deleting Cache
- Changing Browser/Computer
- Pushing changes again
- Modifying the files directly on GitHub
- Waiting around 1 hour

Still, I can see the changes locally and on the repository, but not in the actual website. Why? What should I do? Thank you!

Comment: GitHub is experiencing technical difficulties right now: https://status.github.com/messages. Your issues are most likely related to that. Wait until everything has been resolved, operations are fully restored, and then try again. If it still fails then, let us know.

Comment: Pages should be resumed and working right now, but still my website is 404

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened me. After I merged two branches it created a Jekyl file. I deleted this Jekyl file and the website updated immediately.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31482669)